# creating a cordova application in eclipse from scratch level

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

i'm new to hybrid Mobile App , please can any one will help me step by step  for creating a cordova application in eclipse from scratch level.

and please let me know what are all required software and path has to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps: [Phonegap API Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

If you follow the steps you should have a Hello World app up and running pretty soon.